# Design layout, abstract and table of contents numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, numbering

I have problem with numbering the pages, the `Zusammenfassung` and `Inhaltsverzeichnis` should have the roman numbering on the bottom right, but there is non. See image:

[image: numbering]

Plus, I want all my sections to appear in the header as well. But sadly I have only this, which is also wrong, it should be `1. Motivation` and not `Inhaltsverzeichnis`.

[image]

I got another problem as well, see picture bellow. Why are my sections numbered starting with a 0? It should be `1. Motivation` and `1.1 Motivation 2`

[image]

That's my title.txt:

```
\usepackage[a4paper, left={2.5cm}, right={2cm}, top={3cm}, bottom={3cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\thechapter\ \leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\newcommand{\Title}[8]{


\begin{titlepage}
    
    
        \normalfont \normalsize 
        \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
        \center
        {\LARGE \textsc{TITLE}} \\[4ex]
        {\Large #1 #2}\\
           \vspace*{8ex}
        \HRule \\[0.4cm]
        { \huge \bfseries #3}\\[0.4cm] 
        \HRule \\[1.5cm]
          \vspace*{8ex}
        {\Large #4\\
                #5\\}

    \vspace*{16ex}
    \begin{flushleft}
        {\large
        Betreuung: \\
        #6 \\
        #7 \\
        \vspace*{4ex}
        #8 \\}
    \end{flushleft} 
        
        
    
        
    \end{titlepage}


}
```

That's my main.txt:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\input{vorlage.tex}


\begin{document}

%% TITLESEITE %%
 \Title
      {Test1}   
      {Test2}   
      {xy}                           
      {zz}                            
      {zz}                               
      {test}                       
      {test}                      
      {17. Oktober 2021}     

%% INHALT %% 

\pagenumbering{roman}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Zusammenfassung}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{abstract}
\newpage
\tableofcontents

%% TEXT %%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{sections/motivation}

\end{document}
```

I also have a motivation.txt, looking like this:

```
\section{motivation}
\lipsum[1-6]
\subsection{motivation 2}
\lipsum[1-6]
```

Comment: Is your document long with multiple chapters or short with just a few sections? Will your document be printed doubled sided or single sided? I think you want a separate title page instead of just a document title at the top of the first page, right? Once you have answers for these questions (which isn't yet clear from the questions you've posted), you can move on to what heading levels should appear at the top of what pages, where page numbers go, when there should be no headers/footers, when there should be roman page numbers, and when there should be arabic page numbers.

Comment: @DavidPurton I will have several chapters and it will be printed single sided. I would also like to have a separated title page

Comment: So far none of your documents have included a `\chapter`. As soon as you put a `\chapter` in, your `\section`s will be numbered 1.1, 1.2, etc. Next question: What should go in your header? The chapter name or the section name?

Comment: @DavidPurton Thanks! Section name should be in the header. Also Zusammenfassung (summary) and Inhaltsverzeichnis (table of contents)

Comment: You have to use `\chapter{Motivation}` to get »1 Motivation« and `\section{Motivation 2}` to get »1.1 Motivation 2«.

Answer (score 2):

From your various questions and comments, I think you want something like this:

### Notes

- `report` is a good document class. It uses a separate title page, is one sided, all page styles are the same and it has chapters.
- I used `titlesec` to make chapters look more like normal section headings since this seems to be what you want.
- I used `fancyhdr` to put the name of the current `\chapter` (as well as `\abstractname` and `\contentsname`) in the top left header and the page in the bottom right footer.
- I dropped the `abstract` environment since this is set like a title page for the `report` class and it seems you want it more like a chapter.
- Passing `headheight` to `geometry` is needed since 'Ü' is a bit tall for the default `headheight` and generates a warning from `fancyhdr`.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[headheight=15pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-4ex}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}
    
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\begin{document}

\title{My Document Title}
\author{Mr.~Hanky}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter*{\abstractname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\abstractname}
\markboth{\abstractname}{}

\blindtext[1]

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. With what you've written I get on the first page (1. Überschrift auf Ebene 0 Chapter) in the header "1.1 Überschrift auf Ebene 1". I would like to have the first Title in the header - here it should be "1.Überschrift auf Ebene 0".

Comment: The header should be `1 ̈Uberschrift auf Ebene 0 (chap-ter)` so only the heading in the first level not second

Comment: @Mr.Hankey, I explicitly asked if you wanted chapter or section headings in the header and you said section... But no mind this is easy to change and actually the default. I'll change shortly.

Comment: With LaTeX it it's best to work out document structure first and then document style second. Get your structure right and it's then easier to ask specific questions to change the style.

Comment: I changed the definition of `\chaptermark` and removed the definition of `\sectionmark`.